# What is the meaning of this C++ Error std::length_error

Tags: c++, string, runtime-error

While running my program I get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Abort trap
```

I know that you can't do much without the code but I think that this error is too deep in the code to copy all of it. Maybe I can figure it out if I understand what this error means. 
Is this a sign for an issue with reading or writing at the wrong memory address?

Is there something I can do to get more information about the problem from my program?

Comment: Can u post some piece of code where you are accessing the string ?

Comment: The String is not the problem. After some minor changes and adding debug messages I get a real segfault ;)

Comment: In addition to the answer of Kevin: Maybe you did some calculations that would lead to a negative string length? Because the string length is (normally) stored as an unsigned value your negative value would lead to an extremely large positive value that is mostly greater than std::string::max_size()!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It means you tried to create a string bigger than std::string::max_size().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/as4axahk(VS.80).aspx

> An exception of type length_error Class
>   is thrown when an operation produces a
>   string with a length greater than the
>   maximum size.

Comment: Could that also mean that my string is not in memory anymore and I'm reading random junk from memory until the string is too big?

Comment: You might create this situation accidentily by trying to create a string of size -1. String sizes are unsigned, so -1 is actually the largest possible unsigned integer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question but I just ran into the same issue.
Using Linux with gcc.

Disassembling the function showed a lot of jumps in the code, where the exception was thrown, which shouldn't be there.
In the end, a Clean Build resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

This is an error in debug mode with VS2005. When I change it to release mode, everything works.

Well, the vc debug runtime causes this, that's all.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for posting. 
Please have a look at [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Comment: Switching from Debug to Release worked for me as well, but in VS2008 64-bit. It was crashing when I the debugger was hitting a line that created a very large matrix object. I guess it was trying to allocate enough space to display the matrix as a string and that ended up crashing it.