# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error' what(): basic_string::_S_create

Tags: c++, exception, runtime, mingw

I have the data types given below

```
typedef struct {
    string t;
    string r;
    string c;
    string val;
} cellProperty;

class Fl_Input__: public Fl_Input {
    public:
        explicit Fl_Input__ (int x, int y, int w, int h) : Fl_Input(x,y,w,h) {}
        cellProperty getProperty() { return ownProperty; }
        void setProperty(string t,string r,string c, string val);
    private:
        cellProperty ownProperty;
};
```

I am drawing a GUI via a for loop. Each text input box is a member of a 2d array of `Fl_Input__`. Everything goes fine until the loop reaches point `r=4 & c=7` and throws below exception

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
>
> what():  basic_string::_S_create`

The code compiles and runs fine under linux, I recompiled for win32 (mingw) but having this runtime issue. The code fails where I call setProperty()

```
Fl_Box *tab2ColLabelBox[COLNUM];
Fl_Box *tab2RowLabelBox[ROWNUM];
int t = 1;

for (int r=0 ; r < (ROWNUM + 1) ; r++)
    for (int c=0 ; c < COLNUM ; c++)
    {
        stringstream ss_t, ss_r, ss_c;
        int i_v;

        ss_t << t;
        ss_r << (r-1);
        ss_c << c;

        valueString = readSettings(ss_t.str(), ss_r.str(), ss_c.str());
        SplitString(valueString, v, ",");
        stringstream(v.at(0)) >> i_v;

        tab2OffsetInput[r][c] = new Fl_Input__(
                (CELLWIDTH) * (c+2) + ((c+1) * SIDESPACE) - TXTINWIDTH,
                (r+3) * CELLHEIGHT,
                TXTINWIDTH,
                CELLHEIGHT);
        tab2OffsetInput[r][c]->align(
                FL_ALIGN_LEFT + FL_ALIGN_INSIDE + FL_ALIGN_TOP);
        tab2OffsetInput[r][c]->value(v.at(1).c_str());
        tab2OffsetInput[r]c]->setProperty(
                std::string("1"), ss_r.str(), ss_c.str(), v.at(1));
        tab2OffsetInput[r][c]->maximum_size(3);
        tab2OffsetInput[r][c]->callback(
                callback_modSettings_tab1_txtInput, this);
        v.clear();
    }
```

Any guidance will be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance...

Comment: This isn't the problem, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`Fl_Input__`), along with names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter, are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of this C++ Error std::length\_error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183700/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-c-error-stdlength-error)

Comment: Do we know if `tab2OffsetInput` actually has size `ROWNUM + 1`?

Comment: @LucTouraille, the passed string variables are all single character length, so I do not think the problem I am facing is the same with the one mentioned in the post.

Comment: @BoPersson, the initialization of the `tab2OffsetInput`is like
`Fl_Input__ *tab2OffsetInput[ROWNUM][COLNUM];`
but, there is an if condition for r==0, and c==0, so the boundaries are ok I think.

Comment: But in this loop `for (int r=0 ; r < (ROWNUM + 1) ; r++)` the final value of `r` will be larger than the size of the array. The allowed index values are 0 to ROWNUM-1.

Comment: Ohh...sorry...Actually, there is an `if` condition for for r==0, so the counts match actually (I stripped out that part to simplify the code, sorry,just missed that!)..On the other hand, gdb shows that the error occurs at `tab2OffsetInput[r]c]->setProperty` line only when r==7. I checked all the passed arguments to the function, it seems it is fine, also double check the XML file I am reading from, it is also valid! So, still stack with the same problem :(